# MATLAB real-time plotting from serial port lagging

Tags: matlab, plot, mbed

I am using the code below to plot five analog inputs from a Cortex M3 microcontroller in real-time (live-time). 
I noticed that after some time (few seconds) the plot is legging in response. The lag is of around 10 seconds and apparently it keeps increasing.
When I commented the lines between the asterisks in the code below, I notices that the lag stopped. This was noticed since the LED on the microcontroller module kept blinking at a constant rate. To confirm that it is not from the microcontroller side, I also used Putty where no problems were noticed. So I am assuming that the plotting of the signals is what is causing the problem. Does anyone know why this is happening? anything I can do to solve this problem?

Below is the code used:

```
% Reference: https://developer.mbed.org/cookbook/Interfacing-with-Matlab (SEE 'Serial Communication' SECTION)

delete(instrfindall);             % if any port is already opened by MATLAB its gonna find and close it

TIMEOUT = 5;    %time to wait for data before aborting
XPOINTS = 1000;   %number of points along x axis

try   % this is the try/catch to Handle Errors

    %create serial object to represent connection to mbed
    mbed = serial('COM5', ...
                  'BaudRate', 9600, ...
                  'Parity', 'none', ...
                  'DataBits', 8, ...
                  'StopBits', 1);       %change depending on mbed configuration

    set(mbed,'Timeout',TIMEOUT);        %adjust timeout to ensure fast response when mbed disconnected

    fopen(mbed);        %open serial connection

    position = 1;       %initialise graph variables
    time = 1;
    x = [(1:XPOINTS)' (1:XPOINTS)' (1:XPOINTS)' (1:XPOINTS)' (1:XPOINTS)'];
    xlabels = (1:XPOINTS);
    y = zeros(XPOINTS,5);

    while(1)

        values = fscanf(mbed, '%d,%d,%d,%d,%d');    %get values from serial into vector 

        y(position,:) = values';    %put into y to be displayed

        %update position on x-axis and x-axis labels
        xlabels(position) = time;
        time = time + 1;
        if (position < XPOINTS)
            position = position + 1;
        else
            position = 1;
        end

        %*******************************************************************************************
        %display
        plot(x,y);
        set(gca, 'XTick', 1:XPOINTS);
        set(gca, 'XTickLabel', xlabels);

        drawnow;    %this is required to force the display to update before the function terminates
        %*******************************************************************************************

    end

    fclose(mbed);   %close connection
    delete (mbed)   % deleting serial port object
    clear mbed                               
    clear all

catch
    %in case of error or mbed being disconnected
    disp('Failed!');
    fclose(mbed);   %close connection to prevent COM port being lokced open
    delete (mbed)                             % deleting serial port object
    clear mbed                               
    clear all
end
```

Comment: for starters you keep re-plotting every loop iteration. You can do much better updating XData/YData of existing graphic objects.. Or you can use the new `animatedline` function in MATLAB with nice properties like a rolling functionality dropping old points: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline-object.html